# Запятая перед приложением

Tags: пунктуация

Правда, что 1-й и 2-й варианты правильны, но 3-й – неправильный?

`Я гуляла со своим хорошим другом – Лео.`

`Я гуляла со своим хорошим другом Лео.`

`Я гуляла со своим хорошим другом, Лео.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Все варианты верны**

*Я гуляла со своим хорошим другом Лео* — паузы нет, *Лео* — обычный необособленный член предложения.

*Я гуляла со своим хорошим другом, Лео* — приложение одиночное, имеет пояснительное слово *своим* и обособляется по [2-му пункту Розенталя](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=111). Пауза короткая.

*Я гуляла со своим хорошим другом — Лео* — приложение имеет пояснительный характер, автор подчëркивает его самостоятельность и ставит тире по [10-му пункту](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=111). Пауза длинная.

Ко второму примеру (с запятой) можно из справочника привести несколько примеров:

> Он остановил коня, поднял голову и увидал своего корреспондента, **дьякона**;

> Ухаживала за мной одна девушка, **полька**.

Во всех этих примерах можно поставить **тире**, но пауза будет меньше и будет подчеркиваться **самостоятельность приложений** .

Примеры к примеру номер два (тире):

> Я не слишком люблю это дерево — **осину**;

> В углу гостиной стояло пузатое бюро на пренелепых четырёх ногах — **совершенный медведь**;

> На маяке жил только сторож — **старый глухой швед**.

Во всех этих примеров **тире заменяется на запятую**, но уже не будет так подчеркиваться самостоятельность приложения, да и пауза будет меньше.

---

Вывод: автор может выбрать знак, но будет меняться **пауза** и меньше/больше будет подчëркиваться **самостоятельность приложения**.